# Drag and Drop a popup window in android

Tags: android

It's possible to drag and drop a poupup window in android, I tried with a source code that I found on the internet but I have not come to call drop

Answer (score 2):

Hi i would liked to Share the link which was helped to me in creating the Movable Pop Up Window as Follows:

http://android-er.blogspot.in/2014/01/implement-drag-and-drop-movable.html

i was also implemented the movable pop-up using this link.